problem defining TK() or ttk, what to uses?
I have very simple questions. Can I work with both tk() and ttk, or just one of them?'
I used all the combinations and still getting the same error:
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined.
This is my importing section:
import tkinter as tk
#from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import *

#My window creation section:

root = tkinter.tK()

#sometimes it does not recognize the title sometimes it does. 

root.title("Users List")
#root.iconbitmap()
root.geometry("1000x500")


The purpose of import tkinter as tk is so that you can use the shorter name tk to refer to the module.  So then why are you trying to refer to it as tkinter ?

This question is similar to: What is the difference between the widgets of tkinter and tkinter.ttk in Python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
